# WinForm Button on a black background appears invisible with Visual Styles disabled

Tags: .net, frameworks, visual-styles

i drop a `Button` on a black `Form`. The button appears fine at design time:

[image]

The button also appears fine at runtime (with Visual Styles enabled):

[image]

But the button draws completely wrong with visual styles disabled:

[image]

How to fix?

### Bonus Chatter

- When dropping a `Button` on a black form, the button's `BackColor` sets itself to **black**
- By default a `Button` dropped on a "normal" colored form has a `BackColor` of **Transparent**
- Setting the `Button` `BackColor` to `Transparent` doesn't fix it

Comment: What make you think there is a problem (as you deactivated visual style)? Also, controls in .NET keep track of whether the backcolor has explicitly been set or is inherited from parent control (which is why the color of your control can use the color of the form).

Comment: @ken2k It makes me think it's a problem because a customer reported a problem, which i could reproduce, where "button's are invisible" when running on a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but in case someone else comes across it, I managed to solve the issue in my program. In your `Program.cs` page (or whatever it's been renamed to), ensure you've called [Application.EnableVisualStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) before calling `Run`.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Also ensure that the button's `UseVisualStyleBackColor` property is set to `true`.